# service nginx stop not working on one server but works well on another

Tags: nginx, centos

Both are CentOS servers.

**Server A:**

After running `service nginx stop`, the Nginx processes are killed.

```
ps -aux | grep "nginx"
root      1729  0.0  0.0 125600  6488 ?        Ss   Sep15   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
root      2240  0.0  0.0 125604  5744 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2241  0.0  0.0 125604  5752 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2242  0.0  0.0 125604  4100 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2243  0.0  0.0 125604  5748 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2244  0.0  0.0 125604  4100 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2245  0.0  0.0 125604  4304 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2246  0.0  0.0 125604  5744 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2247  0.0  0.0 125604  5744 ?        S    Sep15   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2248  0.0  0.0 125604  4044 ?        S    Sep15   0:01 nginx: cache manager process
root      3705  0.0  0.0 112708   988 pts/0    S+   21:15   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn nginx


➜  ~ service nginx stop    
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop nginx.service


➜  ~ ps -aux | grep "nginx"
root      3896  0.0  0.0 112704   988 pts/0    S+   21:16   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn nginx
```

**server B:**

After running `service nginx stop`, the Nginx processes are NOT killed at all:

```
[root@machine123 ~]# ps -aux | grep "nginx"
root        1376  0.0  0.1 136592 12592 ?        Ss   09:21   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
root        1388  0.0  0.1 165788 13072 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1389  0.0  0.1 165788 11392 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1390  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1391  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1392  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1393  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1394  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1395  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1396  0.0  0.1 165552  9068 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: cache manager process
root        1892  0.0  0.0  12108  1084 pts/0    S+   09:48   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx


[root@machine123 ~]# service nginx stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop nginx.service


[root@machine123 ~]# ps -aux | grep "nginx"
root        1376  0.0  0.1 136592 12592 ?        Ss   09:21   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
root        1388  0.0  0.1 165788 13072 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1389  0.0  0.1 165788 11392 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1390  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1391  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1392  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1393  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1394  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1395  0.0  0.1 165788  9260 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        1396  0.0  0.1 165552  9068 ?        S    09:21   0:00 nginx: cache manager process
root        1906  0.0  0.0  12108  1028 pts/0    S+   09:49   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Is there anything I can do to debug this?

Thanks for any tips.

`systemctl status nginx` Results:

```
[root@machine123 ~]# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-09-18 09:34:52 CST; 36min ago
  Process: 1868 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1865 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1862 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 18 09:34:51 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:51 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:51 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:51 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:52 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:52 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 18 09:34:52 machine123 nginx[1868]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 18 09:34:52 machine123 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 18 09:34:52 machine123 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 18 09:34:52 machine123 systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Updated in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you've managed to start nginx outside of systemd's control. You should just kill it manually yourself, and then restart it with systemd.

Comment: I use reboot, but when I restart it, it's the same again. I used `service nginx start` to start it, is it wrong?

Comment: If you rebooted the system, the unit is already enabled, so nginx should already start. If it does not start at reboot, you should investigate that, instead of blindly trying to start it again. And yes, you should be using `systemctl`. The `service` command has been deprecated in CentOS since 7.0 (~2014).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

1. Kill the master process:
   kill -9 1376 (PID of nginx master process)
2. Verify again: (make sure cleanly killed nginx and dont have any process using port 80, 443)
   ps -ef | grep nginx
   netstat -naopt | grep 443
3. Start again
   service nginx start